# How to open wa.me link in WhatsApp Business app instead of personal WhatsApp on same phone?

Tags: android, html, angular, whatsapp

We have a web app in Angular 8. We have the following code to show a button that a user can click to send a predefined message via WhatsApp to a contact.

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://wa.me/{{international_formatted_number}}?text={{message}}"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
```

Now the user uses their personal number on WhatsApp, but they are required to send the message via the company number which they use via WhatsApp Business App. Both are on the same android phone. When the user clicks on the button, it opens in WhatsApp, without any prompt to choose between the apps.

Is there any modifier or parameter that can be added to this link so that it opens in WhatsApp Business instead of WhatsApp? Or any other solution?

Expected solution is that when the user clicks to send the WhatsApp message, it opens directly in WhatsApp Business or at least prompts the user to choose between personal WhatsApp or WhatsApp Business.

Comment: I faced a similar issue today. In my case I tried joining a group via a link that was sent to me in Gmail. It kept opening WhatsApp Business instead of regular WhatsApp. One thing that finally worked for me was to copy the link and paste in Samsung Internet browser. It opened WhatsApp webpage with a green join button, that open actually opens an intent to select which WhatsApp.

Comment: + I share a lil post here with steps and photos: http://www.projectnaija.com/topic/selecting-app-to-open-whatsapp-or-whatsapp-business-links-with/2001

Comment: From an end user perspective this looks like a good workaround for now. Thanks @Eaweb. But going forward, there should be some way to redirect the user correctly which the app has predefined.

Comment: Sure! It will be nice if this is an issue that the core android OS team are already looking into. Maybe have some settings screen where users can clear default.

Comment: Anyone can tell me how to do this by modifier or selection in the developed app, not from end user phone.?

Answer (score 10):

If u want to stop sending msgs from Simple WhatsApp & want to send from whatsapp business using wa.me/, then:

Step 1: Long press the simple WhatsApp app

Step 2: Press app info

Step 3: Press Set as default

Step 4: Press Go to Supported URLs

Step 5: Press Always ask

Step 6: Now when you use wa.me/phonenumber  then you will be asked for 1 time to choose WhatsApp simple or business.

Step 7: You choose WhatsApp business

Then for next every time, WhatsApp business will be opened through wa.me/

Now it's all done. Enjoy & remember in prayers.

Comment: This worked with me perfectly, thanks 

Comment: amiin...   \\(._.)/

Answer (score 6):

Just go to app info option (i), then go to default change supported link to open an option to always ask instead default. I had a similar problem and I solved it.

Comment: I was actually looking for some solution to force via the link to ask whether to open the link via WhatsApp or WhatsApp Business. But this is a good solution. Probably the only solution which we can use as this is an internal app, and we can tell our users. Thanks!

Comment: Did not work for me