# Flutter launch business and personal whatsapp programmatically

Tags: flutter, dart

Sorry to ask this here but couldnt find any information related to this online. In native java I have used intent to select `com.whatsapp.w4b` and `com.whatsapp`.

I cant figure out how to do it with dart. So far I know:

```
String androidUrl = 'https://wa.me/$recipientMobile/?text=${Uri.parse(message)}';
String iosUrl = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$recipientMobile=${Uri.parse(message)}';

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  await launch(androidUrl);
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  if(await canLaunch(iosUrl)){
    await launch(iosUrl);
  } else {
    showToast('Error! Try again.', 'Short');
  }
}
```

This code works but only launches default WhatsApp. How to launch bussiness / personal whatsapp?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you find any good solution ? once I have whatsapp business in my phone, it does not work...

Answer (score 1):

EITHER you'll have to ask the users to change the defaults in the link settings of the phone as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69816775/11361894).

OR you'll have to share a link that they paste in the browser which will open the app selection section of the phone with both the options, as shown [here](https://www.projectnaija.com/topic/selecting-app-to-open-whatsapp-or-whatsapp-business-links-with/2001).